# How to store database values in dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

When I receive a country name, I want to search a list of country names in my database and grab the associated id with the country name. Currently I have;

```
    public static int GetCountryId(string countryName)
    {
        int countryId = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(countryName))
        {
            var listOfCountries = GetCountries();
            var match = listOfCountries.FirstOrDefault(item => (item.Name).Contains(countryName));
            if (match != null)
            {
                countryId = match.Id;
            }
        }
        return countryId;
    }

    private static List<Country> GetCountries()
    {
        string query = $"SELECT Id, Name FROM Countries";
        List<Country> cases = Common.GetCollection<Country>(Properties.Settings.Default.DbConnectionString, query);
        return cases;
    }
```

But, as you can see, I have to query the database every time I want to get the list of country names. I want to have it so that this list is stored in a dictionary and I can just access the dictionary instead.

Would anyone know how I could improve my code so that I don't have to access the db each time?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a public dictionary like this:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> countries = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

The method fills the dictionary if its not filled before;

```
private static void GetCountries()
    {
        if(countries.Count == 0)
        {
              string query = $"SELECT Id, Name FROM Countries";
              countries = Common.GetCollection<Country>(Properties.Settings.Default.DbConnectionString, query)
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x=> x.Name);
        }
    }


public static int GetCountryId(string countryName)
{
    return countries.Contains(countryName) CountryIds[countryName] : 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't access non-static members from static methods.

Comment: check the answer again. i fixed it.

Comment: Do you know how the `GetCountryId` method would change with this?

Comment: @user180708 I just edited my answer. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your method like this:

```
private static List<Country> countries;

private static List<Country> GetCountries()
{
    if (countries == null || countries.Count == 0)
    {
        string query = $"SELECT Id, Name FROM Countries";
        countries = Common.GetCollection<Country>(Properties.Settings.Default.DbConnectionString, query);
    }

    return countries;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making a static constructor to populate a dictionary of Country Ids when your program is first started, so that you only have to query the database once. Then calls to GetCountryId can just use that dictionary?

```
private static Dictionary<string, int> CountryIds;

public static NameOfYourClass(){
    CountryIds = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    string query = $"SELECT Id, Name FROM Countries";
    List<Country> cases = Common.GetCollection<Country>(Properties.Settings.Default.DbConnectionString, query);
    foreach (country Country in cases)
    {
        CountryIDs.Add(Country.Name, Country.Id);
    }        
}

public static int GetCountryId(string countryName)
{
    if(!CountryIds.Contains(countryName) return 0;
    return CountryIds[countryName];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a lazy-load for this!

```
private Dictionary<string, Country> _countryNames = null;

public Dictionary<string, Country> CountryNames
{
    get
    {
         if(_countryNames == null)
         {
             _countryNames = new Dictionary<int, Country>();
             foreach(var country in GetCountries())
             {
                 _countryNames.Add(country.Name, country)
             }
         }
         return _countryNames;
    }
}

public static int GetCountryId(string countryName)
{
    Country result;
    CountryNames.TryGetValue(countryName, out result);
    if (result == null) return 0;
    return result.Id;
}

private static IEnumerable<Country> GetCountries()
{
    string query = "SELECT Id, Name FROM Countries";
    return Common.GetCollection<Country>(Properties.Settings.Default.DbConnectionString, query);
}
```

But it's usually even better to let the database do it's thing: run the query there as needed, where you pass the filter string to the database. Unfortunately,  The `Common.GetCollection<T>()` is hiding that ability from us. The `query` variable should look something like this:

```
string query = "SELECT Id, Name FROM Countries WHERE Name = @CountryName";
```

but it's not clear from the question here how to supply the `@CountryName` parameter value. What you should **NOT** do is use string substitution or interpolation to include the value directly in the query string. That would be *very bad*; it creates a serious form a security issued called SQL injection.

Comment: Thank-you for the detailed response! I'm very curious what you mean about string substitution though. If I gave the `@CountryName` parameter how could this be a security threat? I have heard of SQL injection but I do not know how it applies to this situation?

Comment: Why not just one line it with `Lazy<>`?

Comment: If you just do a string replace of the @CountryName value, you will be crazy-vulnerable to attacks. Parameterized queries send the parameter data to the database server separate from the sql command string. But you have to tell the application about the parameter somehow to wire things up.